# An issue when authorizing Facebook pages in Bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework

The issue originates from the bot framework itself, when I add a new Facebook channel for the first time everything works as expected, what I am trying to do is connecting multiple FB pages to the same bot, I read somewhere that you can do this by re-entering the page info and clicking "resubmit", the problem is when the "resubmit" button is clicked without first clicking "Deauthorize" first causes a problem, when I analyzed the request with the browser's inspector it seems that **EnableChannelForBot** method throws an error.

Also we are developing a service where users can register and link their FB pages to the bot just like ChatFuel or any other famous bot platform, the main problem is that bot framework is asking for a specific page id and access token per FB bot and you must do it manually through the bot framework dashboard, can we have an easy way to register the bot to multiple FB pages and without having to do so manually through an API or something Similar? Please work with us to provide a solution for this as soon as you can, Bot Framework is vital to our work and migrating to another SDK is going to be very costly and time-consuming.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that connecting multiple Facebook pages to the same bot is supported. Where did you read that?

Also, there is no API currently you can leverage on to register your bot/enable Facebook channel.

Comment: It was mentioned here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1495

Scroll to the solution provided by Vrety

Comment: Also a more eligant way to handle the exception would be excpected from BF devs not just a disabled button and a console error!